# Why i just got null exception on Throw?

Tags: c#

The code is:

```
catch (WebException ex)
            {
                failed = true;
                wccfg.failedUrls++;
                return csFiles;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                failed = true;
                wccfg.failedUrls++;
                throw;
            }
```

The exception is on the throw;
The exception message is: NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=GatherLinks
  StackTrace:
       at GatherLinks.TimeOut.getHtmlDocumentWebClient(String url, Boolean useProxy, String proxyIp, Int32 proxyPort, String usename, String password) in d:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks-2\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\TimeOut.cs:line 55
       at GatherLinks.WebCrawler.webCrawler(String mainUrl, Int32 levels) in d:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks-2\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\WebCrawler.cs:line 151
       at GatherLinks.WebCrawler.webCrawler(String mainUrl, Int32 levels) in d:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks-2\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\WebCrawler.cs:line 151
       at GatherLinks.WebCrawler.webCrawler(String mainUrl, Int32 levels) in d:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks-2\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\WebCrawler.cs:line 151
       at GatherLinks.BackgroundWebCrawling.secondryBackGroundWorker_DoWork(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\GatherLinks\GatherLinks-2\GatherLinks\GatherLinks\BackgroundWebCrawling.cs:line 82
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
       at System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker.WorkerThreadStart(Object argument)
  InnerException:
```

This is the try code it's inside the WebCrawler function:

```
public List<string> webCrawler(string mainUrl, int levels)
        {

            busy.WaitOne();


            HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
            List<string> webSites;
            List<string> csFiles = new List<string>();

            csFiles.Add("temp string to know that something is happening in level = " + levels.ToString());
            csFiles.Add("current site name in this level is : " + mainUrl);

            try
            {
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = TimeOut.getHtmlDocumentWebClient(mainUrl, false, "", 0, "", "");
                done = true;

                Object[] temp_arr = new Object[8];
                temp_arr[0] = csFiles;
                temp_arr[1] = mainUrl;
                temp_arr[2] = levels;
                temp_arr[3] = currentCrawlingSite;
                temp_arr[4] = sitesToCrawl;
                temp_arr[5] = done;
                temp_arr[6] = wccfg.failedUrls;
                temp_arr[7] = failed;

                OnProgressEvent(temp_arr);


                currentCrawlingSite.Add(mainUrl);
                webSites = getLinks(doc);
                removeDupes(webSites);
                removeDuplicates(webSites, currentCrawlingSite);
                removeDuplicates(webSites, sitesToCrawl);
                if (wccfg.removeext == true)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < webSites.Count; i++)
                    {
                        webSites.Remove(removeExternals(webSites,mainUrl,wccfg.localy));
                    }
                }
                if (wccfg.downloadcontent == true)
                {
                     retwebcontent.retrieveImages(mainUrl); 
                }

                if (levels > 0)
                    sitesToCrawl.AddRange(webSites);



                if (levels == 0)
                {
                    return csFiles;
                }
                else
                {


                    for (int i = 0; i < webSites.Count(); i++)
                    {


                        if (wccfg.toCancel == true)
                        {
                            return new List<string>();
                        }
                        string t = webSites[i];
                        if ((t.StartsWith("http://") == true) || (t.StartsWith("https://") == true)) 
                        {
                            csFiles.AddRange(webCrawler(t, levels - 1));
                        }

                    }
                    return csFiles;
                }



            }

            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                failed = true;
                wccfg.failedUrls++;
                return csFiles;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                failed = true;
                wccfg.failedUrls++;
                throw;
            }
        }
```

This is how im using the wccfg in the top of the class:

```
private System.Threading.ManualResetEvent busy;
        WebcrawlerConfiguration wccfg;
        List<string> currentCrawlingSite;
        List<string> sitesToCrawl;
        RetrieveWebContent retwebcontent;
        public event EventHandler<WebCrawlerProgressEventHandler> ProgressEvent;
        public bool done;
        public bool failed;

        public WebCrawler(WebcrawlerConfiguration webcralwercfg)
        {
            failed = false;
            done = false;
            currentCrawlingSite = new List<string>();
            sitesToCrawl = new List<string>();
            busy = new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(true);
            wccfg = webcralwercfg; 
        }
```

Comment: Please include the "Try" portion of this code.

Comment: are you sure `wccfg` is not null in all `catch` blocks?

Comment: Think that maybe that's the exception that you *caught*? What do you expect *throw* to do otherwise?

Comment: The wccfg is not null . The program worked for like 20-30 seconds then at some point it throwed the exception.

Comment: Added the wcffg code part to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting the `NullReferenceException` because you failed to initialize something before using it in your try block.

The code then enters your `catch(Exception ex)` block which increments the counter, sets `failed=true`, and then re-throws the `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 1):

Something is unhappy with this function call:

```
TimeOut.getHtmlDocumentWebClient(mainUrl, false, "", 0, "", "")
```

The reason the debugger stopped on your `throw` statement is because you caught the original exception, hiding it from the debugger.  Set your debug options for "Break on First-Chance Exception" -- then you will see where the exception truly came from, be able to inspect your variables, etc.

It's usually a good idea to `#if` away any catch-all exception handlers during debugging, since they swallow a lot of important error information.  For what you're doing, it would probably be better to use `try`/`finally` anyway.